# Opening file to write to in the same directory as the program, however, file cannot be found

Tags: c, file, pointers, null

I am trying to write to a file, however, the file pointer is always pointing to NULL as if the file does not exist. The file is in the same directory as the input file, which is found and written to. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
  FILE *vmoutput = NULL;
  fopen("vmoutput.txt", "w");

  // if file could not be opened return error
  if(vmoutput == NULL)
  {
    printf("FILE COULD NOT BE FOUND\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: If you are testing this on the server - make sure that the file you are trying to write to has the proper file permissions set. Incorrect Read and Write permission values will behave as a missing document.

Comment: You need to assign the result of `fopen()` to `vmoutput`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that. @DavidBowling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you fix your code to:

- store and check `fopen`'s return value
- report the actual error

?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

...
FILE *vmoutput = fopen("vmoutput.txt", "w");
if (vmoutput == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", "vmoutput.txt", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

Right now your code always sets `vmoutput` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I could check for actual errors like that. That'll definitely be something I'll be using in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Upon successful completion fopen() return 
>   a
>          FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate
>          the error.

So you have to assign the value returned from `fopen()` to your variable like this. You should also indent your code well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *vmoutput = NULL;
    vmoutput =fopen("vmoutput.txt", "w");
    // if file could not be opened return error
    if(vmoutput == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidBowling  I tought it was trivial. From manual: *The  perror()  function produces a message on standard error describing the last error encountered during a call to a system or  library  function.[...] Then  an  error message corresponding to the current value of errno and a new-line.*

Comment: But you need to ` #include <errno.h>` to use errno variable. I added the header and deleted the errno assignment.

Comment: You do not need to use `errno` with `perror()`. [You only need to `#include <stdio.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) unless you are explicitly using `errno` within your code. You need it if you are using `strerror()`, for example.

Comment: @DavidBowling Just a misunderstanding.Since I don't set `errno` anymore I don't need his header anymore. You're right.